# Shiny input Text popup

Tags: popup, shiny

I would like to get an inpuText popup appearing as soon as I launch my shiny app but I don't know how doing that.
Does someone know how doing that ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I guess this can be accomplished using conditionalPanel and a little css:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  userInput <- eventReactive(input$submit, input$text)
  output$usertext <- renderUI( p(paste("User Input:", userInput()))) 
  }

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(uiOutput("usertext")),        
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.submit == 0", 
      wellPanel(style = "position: absolute; width: 30%; left: 35%; top: 40%; 
                         box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px grey;",
                textInput("text", "Text Input:"),
                actionButton("submit", "Submit"))
      )
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

the shinyBS package allows you to create tooltips and popovers bootstrap-style. It's already on CRAN so you can just install it using install.packages("shinyBS"). See: https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/